# application pool crash

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I  have a problem in SharePoint 2013 I can't resolve.

Application pools containing SharePoint web applications randomly crash.
This results in low performance and connection problems in SharePoint site on crashed web applications.
The error in windows event viewer :

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time
>   stamp: 0x5215df96 Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1590.0,
>   time stamp: 0x5787ef69 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
>   0x0000000000002c0d Faulting process id: 0x6750 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d238cd0d6467e9 Faulting application path:
>   c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Report Id:
>   9b64b752-a4c1-11e6-80eb-d8d385fd6488 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

after that:

> Fault bucket , type 0 Event Name: APPCRASH Response: Not available Cab
>   Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: w3wp.exe P2: 8.5.9600.16384 P3: 5215df96 P4:
>   clr.dll P5: 4.6.1590.0 P6: 5787ef69 P7: c0000005 P8: 0000000000002c0d
>   P9:  P10:

in the same time a warning in system log :

> A process serving application pool 'mums_app2' suffered a fatal
>   communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The
>   process id was '26448'. The data field contains the error number.

I checked files in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue 
but I can't find any more information
what can I do?

Comment: What does the ULS-Log show?

Answer (score 3):

There can be numerous of errors to the web site, the application pool, the application pool account or the web application itself.

If you don't have custom solutions I'd follow these steps:

I would, in my acceptance test environment, delete the web application, the iis website **but NOT the content database**! I would then create a new web application, with a host name on port 80 and the same URL as the deleted one. I'd paste the database name, and create a new application pool with my SP_PortalAppPool account, and see if that solves the problem. If it does, I'd repeat the steps (and take a backup of the Content_DB and proceed with the same steps above.